# Pallet generate store is deprecated how to avoid this warning and compile the code?

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, rust, storage

I am getting error in `#[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]` which is  showing deprecated warning due to which I could not compile my custom pallet is there any solution

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove that line.

```rs
#[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
```

---

For more detail, check https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13535.